# include files in Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, include-path, codelite

I'm not good in Linux.  I'm trying to build CodeLite from source.  The directions on CodeLite's web site ([here](http://codelite.org/Developers/Linux)) are insufficient for me to perform the build.  I think I am just lacking knowledge of the build system in Linux. The build step I am at is `make -j4`.  The error I am currently facing is:

```
fatal error: wx/wxsqlite3.h No such file or directory
```

I have found that file on my system at

```
/home/moving2/sdk/wxsqlite3/include/wx/wxsqlite3.h
```

The best guess I have is that the include path needs to be added in my environment?  So I have tried adding this to the `PATH` string in my `environment` file located in `/etc/` but I get the same error.  How do I get the compiler to look there for my include file?

Comment: You need to edit makefile(s) and add that directory to include list. How to that in your particular case depends on your makefile

Comment: Best option: install your distribution's development package for wx instead of building your own local copy.  This will almost certainly solve the problem.

Comment: No! Never put crap in your PATH, that's a recipe for disaster, and it won't work here anyway. That's Windows-think. Include paths are for the C compiler, so you have to pass "-I/home/..." to the gcc command line somehow, probably by putting that in your Makefile.

Comment: Alternative: pass an `-I` flag to the compiler indicating where to find the headers (i.e. `-I/home/moving2/sdk/wxsqlite3/include`).  The compiler does not rely on the path to executables (`PATH`) to find header files.

Comment: Actually CodeLite is cmake based, you need to realize how cmake searches for wx

Answer (score 1):

If you look into [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/eranif/codelite/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt) file there is a clue there:

> -DWITH_WXPATH=                   // Specify a particular wxWidgets build to use. The format must be /path/to/different_wx-config/directory/

so rerun `cmake` with flags you used before and add `-DWITH_WXPATH=/home/moving2/sdk/wxsqlite3` then run `make` again